# Unable to see shelved Perforce Changelist in UI

Tags: version-control, perforce, shelve, changelist

I generally shelve my Perforce change lists the following way:

1. Right click the pending changelist.
2. Click on Shelve.
3. Unshelve later by right clicking the shelved changelist and click Unshelve.

But not for some reason, I do not see these options in the UI.

So, I shelved my Changelist from the command line using

p4 shelve -c 'change number'

This worked for me, but the problem is that in the P4 GUI, it still shows as a pending changelist and not as a shelved one.

How do i fix this and get things working fine in the UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering here because i was able to figure out the answer to the problem.

My workstation was reformatted recently and the reinstalled version of Perforce client installed was dated back to 2009. That explains why i was able to see Shelving support in UI previously but not after the reformatting.

I remembered vaguely that the Shelving support was relatively recent, so i upgraded to the latest P4V version and i am able to control everything through UI now.

Hope this helps anyone else facing a similar problem.